# Exact Word Matching in a Comma Separated Column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I need to display Exact Number Matching in a Comma Separated Column in Laravel

my column has following values

[image]

I try to select record where notification_to column have exact number of 12 not 120, 128.

```
 $getallrecords=Notifications::Where('notification_to','like',$userid.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `find_in_set` for search for **comma separate** values.

```
$getallrecords=Notifications::whereRaw("find_in_set('".$userid."',notifications.notification_to)")->get();
```

**Edit :** As @Jerodev comment about prevent sql injections you may use it like this as well.

```
->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, notifications.notification_to) > 0", [$userid])
```

The return value is greater than zero, as opposed to non NULL.

**Or**

```
->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, notifications.notification_to)", [$userid])
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but consider using bindings to prevent sql injections.

Comment: Edited answer, correct if it's still wrong. Thank you @Jerodev

Comment: have you got your solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should works to find exact string match.

```
$data = DB::table("notifications")
           ->select("*")
           ->whereRaw("find_in_set(".$userid.",'notification_to')")
           ->get();
```